# Mifare Classic 1k Block access without key

Tags: rfid, mifare

For a special project I need to remove the keys from a Mifare classic 1k card so the values are accessible without any keys (even not the standard key ffffffffffff). Is there any way to set the access bits in a way that no authentication is required to read block content? Like access bit with condition „always access“

Is there a possibility to get the Chinese gen 1a magic cards to a permanent unlocked mode so the reader can read block data no matter what key the reader entered for access?

Or is there any other way?
Thank you
Best regards

I tried experimenting with access bits without success.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to read the data from a sector in MIFARE Classic 1K or 4K chips without authentication.